# Remapping Win+Tab to Ctrl+Alt+Tab with Autohotkey?

Tags: windows-8, autohotkey

I'm trying to remap <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> using Autohotkey, in a way that each time I hit <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it would send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> instead.

I have this so far, but I'm not sure why it isn't working. I checked the documentation on Autohotkey and everything seemed right..

```
Rwin & Tab::send, CtrlAltTab
```

I was hoping someone could help me with this, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't check this because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't seem to do anything on my machine, but the code would probably be:

```
Rwin & Tab::Send, ^!{Tab}
```

If this doesn't work, check first with either SoundBeep, 500, 500 or a normal character. If the SoundBeep, 500, 500 or normal character in e.g. Notepad doesn't work either, you might have to run AutoHotKey in Admin mode (Windows 8 issue).

The alternative that Aaron Miller came up with should be:

```
RWin & Tab::Send {Ctrl Down}{Alt Down}{Tab}{Alt Up}{Ctrl Up}
```

But as said again, test FIRST if AutoHotKey does work in Windows 8 with something simple like e::a . There is a good chance it does NOT, unless you run it with Admin rights (right click run as...)

I realize why <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work on my machine. I disabled Flip 3D!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still doesn't work.

Edit: I didn't know pressing enter would send the comment, sorry.

On Windows 8, it should open the Alt-Tab, without having to hold Tab, http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Windows_8.html#link_3.

When I press the keys normally, it works fine, but not with the keys remapped with Autohotkey.

Comment: Gordon, I still have not seen confirmation that AutoHotKey does work in your Windows 8 environment. I want to see proof of that before trying to tackle this code. create a script with e.g. F1::SoundBeep, 500, 500 run that script and see what happens when you press [F1].

Comment: Robert, when I press F1, a beep comes out of my computer speakers.

Comment: Perfect, Next try F1::SendInput, ^!{Tab} or of that doesn't work just F2::SendInput, Hello  and then press F2 when Notepad is active.

Comment: F1 doesn't work, but F2 works and types out "Hello".

Comment: Great, Let's now try F1::SendInput, {Ctrl Down}{Alt Down}{Tab}{Alt Up}{Ctrl Up}

Comment: Once that works, you can test: >#Tab::SendInput, {Ctrl Down}{Alt Down}{Tab}{Alt Up}{Ctrl Up}  Background: > = Right, # = Win, technically  >#Tab::SendInput, ^!{Tab} should work as well. Using >#Tab is often easier than RWin & Tab because once you combine keys with &, the first key looses it's orginal function, which can be restored with RWin::RWin, but it requires an extra line.

Comment: F1::SendInput, {Ctrl Down}{Alt Down}{Tab}{Alt Up}{Ctrl Up} did not work... I minimized everything and pressed F1 and nothing happened or triggered.

Comment: Gordon, I just read-up on this and it seems that this is a Windows 8 specific issue. Read this thread: http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/85747-mapping-ctrl-alt-tab-to-a-single-key/

Comment: Ahh, I see, thank you so much Robert for helping me out. I wish I had reputation to upvote you.

Comment: Gordon, you could do me a favor by "accepting" my answer. Click on the white "check-mark" next to the answer. The white check-mark will turn green.

Answer (score 2):

Find `Window Switcher.lnk` 
in `C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch` and activate this link with any shortcut you want.

Answer (score 1):

`CtrlAltTab` doesn't seem to mean anything special to AutoHotkey, per its documentation; if anything, I'd expect it to send the literal string. (Try it while a Notepad window has focus; it seems likely the result would be "CtrlAltTab" entered into the Notepad window as though you'd typed it.)

Instead, try this:

```
RWin & Tab::Send {Ctrl}{Alt}{Tab}
```

or perhaps this, which would affect both Windows keys:

```
#Tab::^!{Tab}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but that still doesn't work for me. Ctrl+Alt+Tab is supposed to trigger [this](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/win/Windows_8.html#link_3) on Windows 8. With the first string, nothing happens. The second one gives me an error that the command is not recognized.

Comment: @GordonPham-Nguyen: For the record Ctrl+Alt+Tab works the same way in Win7 as well. Win+Tab and Ctrl+Win+Tab in Win7 activate Flip3D.

Comment: To those who edited: Good work in general, but in this case, the edit was bogus because what's intended there is not a combination of the three keystrokes, but rather the literal string `CtrlAltTab` -- hence the use of backticks in one instance, and double-quotes in the other.

Answer (score 0):

#InstallKeybdHook

```
RWin::
```

If ( GetKeyState("Tab", "P") ) {
    Msgbox,`n (%A_ScriptName%~%A_LineNumber%) 
  }
    return
    LWin::
    If ( GetKeyState("Tab", "P") ) {
    Msgbox,`n (%A_ScriptName%~%A_LineNumber%) 
  }
    return